# invoke filter inside controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

What I'm trying to do is filter a model value inside controller vía number filter, inside a watch funcion, this is the code:

```
  .controller('FormSectionCtrl', function ($scope,$filter) {
        console.log( $filter('number')(2.4334444,2));   // At this point, the filter works, the problem starts inside de watch...

        $scope.$watch('input19 * constan1 + input20 * constant2', function (value) {

        // $scope.input23 = value;   ...if I do this, the value is correct but with too much digits after point...I just want 2 digits...

        $scope.input23 = $filter('number')(value);  // It doesn't works...
  });
})
```

For some reason the $filter doesn't display nothing inside the watch...Anybody has an idea about how to do this properly?

Comment: This should work. Setup a plunker.

Comment: Do you need a ",2" in your second filter like you have in your first?

Comment: Thanks by answer guys... I did what you said...I've created a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/cpB559NPrmdmCUa1zHGZ?p=preview) and I've added the ",2" also, and yes, that code works well at plunker but my app not yet...I've checked and I don't have other code in that scope...